# can't get results in a query in DBpedia and sparql

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

This is my query, it runs ok but gives me no result.

```
    SELECT ?instance_of ?label_he ?label_en ?place_of_birth ?date_of_birth ?place_of_death ?date_of_death ?URL
WHERE { ?link a foaf:Person. ?link ?p ?person_full_name. 
FILTER(?p 
IN(dbo:birthName,dbp:birthName  ,dbp:fullname,dbp:name)).
  ?instance_of rdfs:label ?label_he.
  ?instance_of rdfs:label ?label_en.
  ?instance_of dbo:P19 ?place_of_birth.
  ?instance_of dbo:P569 ?date_of_birth.
  ?instance_of dbo:P20 ?place_of_death.
  ?instance_of dbo:P570 ?date_of_death.
  ?link rdfs:label ?person_name . ?person_name bif:contains "Tim_Cook" . 
  OPTIONAL { ?instance_of dbo:P31 ?record_label. }
  OPTIONAL { ?instance_of dbo:P31 ?instance_of. }
  OPTIONAL { ?instance_of dbo:P2699 ?URL. }
FILTER(langMatches(lang(?person_full_name), "en")) . }
```

Can't understand what is wrong
Thank You!

Comment: You should use `dbo:birthPlace` instead of `dbo:P20` etc, `rdf:type` instead of `dbo:P31`. Look into [this page](http://dbpedia.org/page/Albert_Einstein) in order to understand which "biographical" properties are used in DBpedia.

Comment: How many questions do you want to open in order to solve the same task?! Now we have 4 questions ... and to be honest, I'm wondering whether you understood any of the SPARQL queries. You got the current from a users comment, then changed it to Wikidata entities somehow, now back to DBpedia prefixes.